# Tab host goes over right border

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I've created Tab host and added several tabs. Everything works fine but when I scroll to the right it continue going over last tab border into undefined dark space until Tab host become completely invisible. Scrolling to the left works fine. 
Any idea for this issue?

Thank you.

Edit:

```
 <TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0.5dip"
                android:background="#000" />

            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000">
                <HorizontalScrollView 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                    >

                    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        />

            </HorizontalScrollView>
            </LinearLayout> 

            <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="4dp"
                android:background="#696969" />

            <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="0px" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

Comment: Posted. Interesting thing is that this issue occurs only on 4.0. On 2.3 works fine :/

Comment: Why do you need HorizontalScrollView ower your tabwidget? Also i noticed in my projects that tab bar does not work properly if tab widget is not given height:match_parent

Comment: I've just solved it somehow :) It was something related to height and width but not sure. Thank you